# Can GeoMesa handle point with a time line segment

Tags: geomesa

i know that GeoMesa can index spatial-temporal shape like a space line segment with a timestamp tag, but in my work, one object may stay at a location(Point) for a period of time (logintime+duration), so how can i handle such line segment in time dimension rather than space dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your geometries are stored as points, I would suggest indexing your start time as the default `Date`, and then adding a second field for duration or end time. The spatio-temporal index would only allow querying on the start time, but you can filter on the end time as a secondary predicate.

If your geometries are stored as line strings, then you can create `List[Date]` attributes to store start/end time per point. You would still need a single `Date` attribute for the spatio-temporal index, however.

The underlying XZ index structure used by GeoMesa can handle time extents, but indexing them has not been implemented (yet). However, if it's something that users want, it could be added to the roadmap.